# Имя таблицы в sqlite через переменную

Tags: python, sqlite

Хочу называть новую таблицу через переменную, все принципе понятно как сделать, но почему мой способ не работает?

```
name = "water"

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE ? (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date DATE, old_counter TEXT, new_counter TEXT, odds TEXT, tarrif TEXT, summa TEXT)",name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В качестве SQL параметров можно передавать только [литералы (фиксированные значения)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)), но не имена таблиц, столбцов или другие части SQL.

Вы можете собрать SQL динамически:

```
q = """
CREATE TABLE {table} (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  date DATE, 
  old_counter TEXT, 
  new_counter TEXT, 
  odds TEXT, 
  tarrif TEXT, 
  summa TEXT)
"""
```

и вызывать следующим образом:

```
cur.execute(q.format(table='my_table'))
```

Как заметил @Fat-Zer, для того, чтобы избежать неприятных ситуаций (пробелы в имени, использование зарезервированных слов, etc.) лучше "экранировать" имена таблиц (столбцов и т.д.):

SQLite поддерживает четыре вида экранирования:

1. "keyword" (двойные кавычки)  [`ANSI SQL-99 Standard`]
2. 'keyword' (одинарные кавычки)
3. [keyword] квадратные скобки
4. `keyword` обратные кавычки

Comment: не хватает жирного напоминания, о том, что если имя таблица получается, от пользователя, то его надо квотировать и экранировать...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, хорошая идея, спасибо!

Comment: из указанных способов, для имён стандартный—это двойные кавычки. Одинарные кавычки используются для строковых констант (sqlite может правила слегка нарушить (не рекомендуется) и по контексту как имя использовать (когда строка не допускается в этом месте)). `[]` это не стандартный SQL (используется в SQL Server). ```` это не стандартный SQL (используется в MySQL)¶ Рекомендуется по умолчанию экранирование использовать: `f'create table "{table}" (...)'` https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: @jfs, спасибо, добавил соответствующий комментарий