# форматирование строки перед передачей запроса в mysql python

Tags: mysql, python, строки, форматирование

Ребят вопрос в чем отличае между

`exec_DB("UPDATE 'Main' SET %s = %s" % (mmod[m], val))` и

`exec_DB("UPDATE 'Main' SET %s = %s", (mmod[m], val)`

это из-за repr ? 
его надо переопределять в питоне? можете обьяснить в двух словах, пока точное определения на гуглить не могу!

функция:

```
def exec_DB(sql, params=()):
    try:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect (host, user, passwd, db)
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR CONNECT DB >>>> ' + str(e))
    conn.text_factory = lambda x: unicode(x, "utf-8", "ignore")
    try:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR exec_DB: ' + str(e))
    finally: conn.close()
```

Comment: что такое `exec_DB()`? какие параметры принимает?

Comment: такая функция:  def exec_DB(sql, params=()):
    try:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect (host, user, passwd, db)
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR CONNECT DB >>>> ' + str(e))
    conn.text_factory = lambda x: unicode(x, "utf-8", "ignore")
    try:    
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql, params)
        conn.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print('ERROR exec_DB:  ' + str(e))
    finally:
        conn.close()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В первом случае вы форматируете строку и передаете ее целиком `exec_DB(...)`:

```
In [105]: m, val = 2, 155

In [106]: print("UPDATE 'Main' SET %s = %s" % (mmod[m], val))
UPDATE 'Main' SET config_user = 155
```

**Осторожно!** Используя непараметризованные SQL вы рискуете стать жертвой ["SQL Injection"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_SQL-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Пример: пользователь ввел следующие значения:

```
In [107]: m, val = 2, "155; drop table `Main`;"
```

после форматирования получим следующий SQL (обратите внимание на вторую команду `drop table ...`):

```
In [108]: print("UPDATE 'Main' SET %s = %s" % (mmod[m], val))
UPDATE 'Main' SET config_user = 155; drop table `Main`;
```

во втором вы передаете `exec_DB()` строку `UPDATE 'Main' SET %s = %s` и в качестве второго аргуметна - кортеж значений.

Если `exec_DB()` - это аналог `cursor.execute()` из `SQL Alchemy`, то такой вариант работать не будет т.к. [параметризировать можно только литералы, но не имена таблиц, столбцов, etc.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803700/%D0%98%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%B2-sqlite-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E)

Сделать это можно так:

```
q = """UPDATE 'Main' SET {column_name} = ?"""
exec_DB(q.format(column_name=mmod[m]), (val,))
```

сформатированный SQL:

```
In [110]: print(q.format(column_name=mmod[m]))
UPDATE 'Main' SET config_user = ?
```

Comment: спасибо, познавательно!