# Почему при вставке в таблицу передаваемые значения воспринимаются как названия столбцов?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Хочу полученные от пользователя данные сохранять в БД. Но код ниже не работает.

Не находит колонки, что верно, такой колонки нету, потому что `Uus` - это введенные данные пользователем, а не название колонки в таблице в БД.

Ошибка:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Uus

Код сохранения переданных данных пользователем (name_, surname_, age_) в таблицу `Profiles(id, First_name, Last_name, Age)`:

```
def save_to_sqllite(name_,surname_,age_):
conn = sqlite3.connect(os.path.join(PATH,'Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite')) #подключаемся к БД
cursor = conn.cursor() #создаем курсов для обработки запросов к БД
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Profiles")
next_ID = cursor.fetchall()[0][0] + 1
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Profiles (id, First_name, Last_name, Age) VALUES ({next_ID},{name_},{surname_},{age_});")
conn.commit() #сохраняем изменения в БД
conn.close() #закрываем подключение к БД
return print(f'saved')
```

Подскажите, почему в строке:

```
cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO Profiles (id, First_name, Last_name, Age) VALUES ({next_ID},{name_},{surname_},{age_});")
```

передаваемые значения воспринимаются, как названия столбцов?

И как сделать так, чтобы вставлять данные от пользователя в нужные столбцы в таблице?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В SQLite приходит следующая команда (я подставил случайные значения переменных):

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (id, First_name, Last_name, Age) 
VALUES (123, Vasiliy, Pupkin, 25)
```

Строковые литералы в SQL должны быть обрамлены одиночными кавычками - иначе они воспринимаются как имена столбцов/таблиц или других БД объектов (например индексов или `constraints`):

```
INSERT INTO Profiles (id, First_name, Last_name, Age) 
VALUES (123, 'Vasiliy', 'Pupkin', 25)
```

Но вместо подстановки значений при помощи форматирования, гораздо лучше использовать параметры - драйвер БД сам займется квотированием строковых литералов:

```
sql = """INSERT INTO Profiles (id, First_name, Last_name, Age) VALUES(?,?,?,?)"""
params = (next_ID, name_, surname_, age_)
cursor.execute(sql, params)
```

где `id, First_name, Last_name, Age` - реальные наименования столбцов таблицы БД, а `next_ID, name_, surname_, age_` - имена существующих переменных в Python скрипте.

Всегда старайтесь использовать параметры в SQL запросе вместо подстановки значений переменных в тело SQL запроса - это поможет избежать [SQL Injections](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804422/211923).
Кроме того для большинства БД это также будет работать быстрее, т.к. при повторном использовании этого запроса - его уже не надо будет парсить, проверять на синтаксис, проверять права доступа и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало.